# CSS: set width div to match screen edge

Tags: css

I have a position:absolute div element, whose position is known only at runtime, and I want it keep its left position but extend towards the screen-edge.
In other words, I want to set the width of the div to the screen width minus the value of "left":

```
.mydiv {
   position: absolute;
   width: calc(100% - left);
}
```

The above try to access the value of "left" has proven unsuccessful.

When I just set "right" to zero, like this, a narrow div is moved to the right screen edge, but does not keep the left position it otherwise would:

```
.mydiv {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
```

I would like to keep the "left" position as it is and extend the div to the right screen edge.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't set it's width!

If the div's parent is say `body`... just add:

```
right: 0;
```

Example:

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}


.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; /* tyadaa! */
  height: 20px;
}

#one {
  left: 78px; /* or unknown */
  background: red;
  top: 50px;
}

#two {
  left: 26%; /* or unknown */
  background: blue;
  top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="mydiv"></div>
<div id="two" class="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, because I don't have a fixed "left" value as you have.

Comment: That means that if the div is having narrow content, it will only be on the right edge of the screen: I want to keep the value of "left" as I explained in the question

Comment: The div is placed in the flow and it depends on the other content where it is positioned. (dynamic) For your use-case, there is no problem because I could just use calc(100% - 78px)

Comment: @RolandSeuhs I think I understand now. But you should make your case clearer in your question :) So, as I've understand it - say the div is inside a flexible page-centered column (like a usual centered content area) - you want to additionally extrude/extend that element to touch the right window's border edge?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I clarified the question.